# Content after div with absolute position and auto height

Tags: css, position

Good afternoon!

I am trying to make this work - I have one `<div>` with `position: absolute` and `height: 100%; min-height: 100%;` so height is auto. And I would like to place another `<div>` after this one, but I don't know, how many % should I use at margin-top, or which kind of position...
Here is my code, I would be glad for every advice! Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div id="content">

...text text text...

</div>


<div class="clr"></div>

<div id="copyright">
text text...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
background: url('bg_blue.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}

.clr {
  clear: both;
} 

 #copyright {
position: static;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it make sense to have `margin-top` be the `height` of the preceding element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes It is possible easily by `position: relative;` and `float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with `position: relative;` and `float: left;`